# How to change the border colour for the button and changing the colour for underline in the editText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

I have tried many methods but my issues is not solved.I am facing the issue in changing the colour for the border of the button and underline in the editText. In changing the colour of the button the background colour should be transparent but the border of the button should be visible in white colour. EditText underline colour is should be in white. How to create the design like below image.[image]

Please help me how to design Login with Facebook button border is in white colour should be visible and also edittext underline colour should be in white.

Comment: use this linnk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690416/android-border-for-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - border for button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690416/android-border-for-button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

For `Edittext` underline color use:

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
```

For `Button` background:

drawable/background.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <!--stroke width and color-->
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- corner radius-->
    <corners
        android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

And in layout:

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:text="Login With Facebook"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

**EDIT**

```
backgroungTint will not work on Pre lollipop devices
```

try using this:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/my_appcompat_imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
    android:tint="@android:color/white" />
```

output:

[image]

Comment: I solved this , please help me how to solve changing the editText underline colour

Comment: in your `values/color.xml` u need to add this `<color name="White">#ffffffff</color>`

Comment: The error is shown in "R.color.White" error is should pass the resolved colour instead of the resource id

Comment: still not changed the color

Comment: sorry for late reply,the edittext  underline colour changes is android sdk emulator but when i run in real device the colour was not changed

Comment: I using the custom edittext,when i run the app in lollypop device the colour changes

Comment: that why i edited the answer ....`backgroungTint will not work on Pre lollipop devices`

Comment: Is there any way to change the colour for pre lollypop device by using the custom edittext

Comment: u can use `style` ..see this [ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480398/edittext-underline-below-text-property)

Comment: I dont know how to apply that style and it not working

Comment: pls go through the answer properly ...it is the 2nd answer...if yet problem not solved post another question so that everyone can help

Answer (score 1):

**Border for Button:** You can set a drawable shape as background of button to change it's border color. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19010696/7235049)

**Change EditText UnderLine:** You can add colorHighlight and colorNormal to your BaseTheme. It will change the underline color of editText. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26631227/7235049).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used your answer but the background color only changed

Comment: try using android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Base to your editText.

Comment: I don't know how to use theme will you help me

Comment: Sure. Copy the solution from the link and paste it in  styles.xml in value folder. Then apply the theme to your editText by adding this - android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Base . Hope this works.

Comment: But the solution is created in the drawable folder then how i can use in style folder

Comment: Sorry, I thought you are talking about editText underine. If you are applying border for button, just set button background as android:background="@drawable/button_boarder"

Comment: I applied your condition but the background colour is not transparent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137915/discussion-between-tahsinrupam-and-prabha-karan).

Answer (score 1):

Just make button_bg.xml file in drawable and put given code below

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="#30055fab" />
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <corners android:radius="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and define button background as above created xml file

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="Log in"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

To add line in editext try this code

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10dp"

        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        app:hintEnabled="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />

        <view
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_height="1dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Do you know how to change the colour for underline in edittext

Comment: Check my edited post xml for adding line under editext the way you wanted to..enjoy :)